# JavaScript Window Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, window-resize

I am using this code to set the height of a section.

```
    //Fixed Image Window Height
                $(window).ready(setSizes);

                function setSizes() {
                   var containerHeight = $("#about").height();
                   $("#about").height(containerHeight - 70);
                }
                $(window).resize(setSizes);
```

I had initially

```
$(window).load(setSize);
```

There seem to be conflicting things going on I believe. How can I write this saying do this when the window loads and also when it gets resized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          setSizes();
});

            function setSizes() {
               var containerHeight = $("#about").height();
               $("#about").height(containerHeight - 70);
            }
```

Try this!

Comment: Awesome thank you! Now if I wanted to set this section to always fill the window height even when the browser is scaled would I just change the first #about to window? It works when I refresh, but gets either longer or shorter depending on which way I'm scaling.

Comment: I guess the  $(window).resize(setSizes); isn't being utilized right?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just added the window.resize above the function and it worked.

Comment: If you want to set #about section fit to your browser scale you can just set #about section's css styling. Set width:100%; and height:100%;. Even if you scale the window, there will be no problem, #about section will always fill window.

Comment: One minor improvement: you don't need to actually say `$(document).ready(function() {...`.  Because it's such a common thing to do jQuery provides a shortcut; you can instead just do: $(function() {...`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote it like this and it seems to work. Not sure if it's bad practice or not, and I haven't really checked cross-browser, but it's functioning.

```
                $(document).ready(function(){
                      setSizes();
            });

            $(window).resize(setSizes);

            function setSizes() {
               var containerHeight = $(window).height();
               $("#about").height(containerHeight - 70);
            }
```